# Jenkins(Hudson): How to setup a mirror CI instance, which builds alternatively

Tags: jenkins

I am looking for ways to setup alternate instances of CI using Jenkins such that, one instance is always available for testing while the other is refreshing with latest changes.

Currently I have only one instance and there's a considerable downtime while it re-builds. Has anyone tried to setup an alternating CI ?

Thanks,

Comment: I think I need to re-frame my question. Here's what I want to do: I need to have two jobs which build on two separate instances. (let's say J1 and J2) When there's a change in SVN, J1 should take up and start building, while J2 instance is still accessible. When there are some more changes, J2 should pick up the changes and start building while, J1 is available for testing. This is to avoid downtime and make the CI instance available at all times.

Comment: Are you saying both J1 and J2 are capable of building and testing you just want them to alternate depending on their current status whether or not they are busy?

Comment: @TylerSmith, yes and no. Both J1 and J2 are capable of building and testing (in fact they are similar jobs with just one difference: the slave on which they build). I would like to build on J1 when J2 has built earlier and vice verse.

Comment: If you literally want them to alternate you might have to get the RSS feed and check which has built last.  There is no built in alternate feature.  Have you tried upping the amount of executors on your slaves for concurrent building and testing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making your main build call a test build that is set to run on a different slave?  You can have jobs tied to slave machines by going to the job config and checking the "Restrict where this project can be run" box.  It will ask you for the name of the slave to tie it to.

Comment: Yes, but that's one time setting. How can I switch between instances?

Comment: oh like have multiple test machines?  If you specify more than one slave machine in the restriction it will pick what ever one is free.  You can also set (in the main jenkins config) to utilize one slave more than another.

Comment: yes I can do that, but Jenkins will pick up the slaves on the availability than the previous history. The main idea is to make the app available for testing without much down time. The build time is around 1 hour, which is causing delays in executing integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by having two different master and slave combination and a custom shell script which alternates between these two setups. Coudn't find any other alternatives, but this works for me.